# Magento2 : Online payment method does not work in Checkout Multiple Addresses

Tags: magento2, payment-methods, payment, payment-gateway, magento2.4.6

we have integrated the Online payment method in our custom extension.
The payment method is showing in multiple addresses.

- https://i.imgur.com/35i79rV.png
  But placing an order using Online payment is not redirecting to the payment gateway page.

Comment: What happens instead ? Is there some error ? This is probably a bug specific with the payment module. Be sure to have the latest version of the module installed. If you still have a problem, you can also contact their support.